# Customizing buttons with psudo elements, only the content is different on each button how to keep DRY

Tags: css

The HTML is a ul with lis containing my nav options like home, contact, about etc... im wondering what the best way to approach adding this effect to each button since each one has different content and will need a different icon.  If you dont feel like reading through the code the functionality is this:

in the HTML where it used to be

HOME

is now erased and replaced with a before pseudo element containing "HOME" which on hover is moved up -20px (the overflow is hidden).
there is an after pseudo element that contains an icon relating to whatever the button is (home icon, book icon etc) and that is positioned below the button and on hover is moved up to the place where the before pseudo element was.

How do I keep this DRY?

here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqzVQe

```
.menu a{
  display:block;
  color:white;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu a::before{
  content: '\f015';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  top:-30px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  color:black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu a:hover::before{
  top: -20px;
}

.menu a::after{
  content: 'Home';
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:calc(100% + 20px);
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu a:hover::after{
  top:50%;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? All you have to do is declare custom `.menu a::before{
  content: '\f015';}` for each button, specifying the icon.

Comment: So should each button have a class?

Comment: he wants to keep it DRY, and i understand that, best is to use something like content: attr(data-icon) to my mind, as you will only need to add the data-icon to the html, and the css will be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before and after have a neat proprety that says content can use data attributes values.

your icon css will look like that,

```
content: attr(data-icon)
```

and you will add the icon in an html data attribute.

```
<li><a href="../nextpage/next.html" data-icon="\f015"></a></li>
```

Demo here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLEYZG

Comment: Great!  So for the text content, will there need to be classes on each li to change the content: ' ABOUT ' to its appropriate button? or is there a better way?

Comment: you mean the word "home" ? it is the exacte same thing, your html will have both a data-icon and a data-word/data-about or whatever you would like to call it